# App Store handling of separate iphone/iPad builds

Tags: iphone, ipad, build, app-store

I have to builds of the same app for iphone and ipad, both are tested on the simulator and devices. Target device family is set to "iphone" resp. "ipad".
I intend to submit these builds to the App Store as separate Apps.
I setup an app id for the iphone app, got the appropiate certificates, created a new app on itunes connect etc.

I am unsure how to proceed with the ipad app:

- Do I have to create a second app id
  and a corresponding app in itunes
  connect?
- If yes, I guess I have to change the bundle id for the ipad build, how can I do that?
- Will the iphone app show up only if I
  browse the app store on an iphone,
  but not when browsing from an ipad
  (and vice versa)?

I googled and searched here and on Apples documentation, I guess it is buried somewhere, but I couldn't find definitive answers.

So pointers to Apples docs (or duplicate questions) would also be greatly appreciated.

As always, thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, you have to. You can change it before build in your Info.plist, or, you can create another Info.plist and use different target to build different apps.
3. iPhone app will be shown on iPad, but iPad will not be shown on iPhone.

So, main thing here is "several targets, one for each platform" and use target settings, not project settings to configure provision profiles.

Comment: 0. Thank you very, very much!
1. Thanks for the definitive answer
2. Of course, separate targets!! I did this already with the resources (each app has resources of 10 MB, that's why I prefer separate apps!).
3. I think I should name the ipad app name

Comment: (5 min limit reached)
3. I think I should then name the ipad app "Appname for iPad" to give users a hint that they should download this app and not the iphone one. Small sub question: Is it ok to use the name "iPad" in app names? I recall Apples docs to forbid mentioning their trademark names...
Again, thank you!

Comment: You can use "for the iPad", or "HD" suffix, it's rather common.

Comment: Ok, thanks again! Just for anyone else stopping by, regarding targets: Copy the Info.plist to some other name, don't change the target settings on the plist (no targets should be selected). Rather, navigate to the target itself (i.e. "myapp-ipad"), get Info and scroll down to packaging. You can edit the corresponding info.plist there. Works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

1. if you have not built a universal app then yes you need create
   second app
2. yes you need to change bundle id for ipad built ,you can change it
   in plist file and keep same as in your itunes connect,you can just
   add ipad at last of ur bundle name then iphone bundle.
3. yes iphone app will only show if you browse in iphone section and if
   you browse in ipad section ipad app will show.

Comment: Thank you too, Kshitiz! Please forgive me for giving the accepted answer to Alexander (for better formatting :)). Are you sure about 3. because Alex says otherwise?

Comment: yes i guess bro coz i am pretty sure , you can see facebook app as example it will not show in ipad section and it run fine in iPad the only thing you need to do is 2X zoom, and almost every iphone app runs fine in ipad as told by apple . and ya i am not talking about universal app because it shows in both iphone and ipad , u c example twitter app as universal app

Comment: Ok, I try to confirm this here once I submitted the app. Thanks again, and have a nice day!

Comment: gr8 man if you get other then my ans let me know, have a gr8 day man

Comment: On iPhone there is no iPad section. On PC or Mac in iTunes there is, so you can browse both. If you'll try to open iPad app in App Store on iPhone, it will tell you that you can't. But on iPad you can browse (search) both iPhone and iPad apps.